# Common Lisp Package and Module Management

Tags: common-lisp, slime, quicklisp

I am currently trying to understand how Common Lisp manages its packages and modules.

Consider this code:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

(ql:quickload :cl-who)
(ql:quickload :hunchentoot)
(ql:quickload :parenscript)

(defpackage :retro-games
  (:use :cl :cl-who :hunchentoot :parenscript))

(in-package :retro-games)

(defclass game ()
            ((name  :initarg  :name)
             (votes :initform 0)))
```

When I create a Slime buffer and then run this code in another buffer that is set to Slime mode, I see some prints in the first buffer that is `*slime-repl sbcl*`:

> Load 1 ASDF system:
>       cl-who ; Loading "cl-who"
>
> To load "parenscript":   Load 1 ASDF system:
>       parenscript ; Loading "parenscript" ..
>
> To load "hunchentoot":   Load 1 ASDF system:
>       hunchentoot ; Loading "hunchentoot" ..............

That is, there seems to be some "talking" going on between the two buffers. However, if I try to run `(make-instance game("Chess"))`, I get an error because the `CL-USER` package does not know about the `game` class.

On the other hand if I run `(in-package :retro-games)` in the `slime repl sbcl` buffer, I am able to run `(make-instance game("Chess"))`.

The question is how does Common Lisp organize its work with packages? On related note, what is the difference between a buffer being a `slime repl sbcl` and a buffer being in `slime-mode`?

Are the packages at all similar to Python's virtual environments? That is, where are the `CL-WHO`, `HUNCHENTOOT` and `PARENSCRIPT` being installed in my case? Do I have any choice over this?

Comment: did you searched for the answer on the net? there is a lot of great material on this subject (ie "Practical Common Lisp - 21. Programming in the Large: Packages and Symbols" by Peter Seibel http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html).

Comment: hi, there was no need of the python and emacs tags.

Comment: Quicklisp is different than Python's virtual environments. Quicklisp builds all libraries together so than they work together. See [this discussion](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-client/issues/148). If you /need/ like a venv, there is [Qlot](https://github.com/fukamachi/qlot).

Answer (score 3):

First, try `(make-instance 'game :name "Chess")`. 
Note that Common Lisp uses prefixed notation between paarenthesis. So, if want to call a function like `foo("bar")`, it would be `(foo "bar")`.
If you want, you can create a function like:

`(defun new-game (game-name)
    (make-instance 'game :name game-name))`

If you are using Quicklisp, the packages me be installed at where you've installed quicklisp. If it is installed at your home folder, the packages should be at `/home/user/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/`.